# Wordpress Civicrm_acl_contact_cache Table got Deleted

Tags: wordpress, database

I am using CiviCRM wordpress version 5.12.3 - For some reason Civicrm_acl_contact_cache table got deleted

I am sure no one has Database access (apart from me). But still the table got deleted. Also, it wasn't fully deleted when I SSH the server I was able to view the table (even I couldn't dump the DB). so, I dropped it through SSH and created again.

I am not sure what triggered the table to drop in the database from front-end.

Has anyone faced the same issue before?

Thanks in advance 

Ramesh Rajendran

Comment: Do you have plenty of disk space?  I've seen weird things happen if you run out of disk space where MySQL stores it files.

Comment: Yes, Server has 100 GB Free space and 64 GB RAM

Comment: I have just recently seen the same phenomenon - just the column definitions where still there, the contents file for the table was missing. This seems to have happened overnight with no user activity. A backup was created after the last activity and before this happened and the table was apparently empty. Currently I am unsure, how to proceed. Would like to hear if you got any more infos. (Using Civi 5.17.5 on WP with separate db)

Comment: @joachim I have given the answer in the question - you need to SSH and drop the table and create a new table - That should work - If you need more help let me know

Comment: Thanks @Ramesh. While the database admin system of my hosting solution failed to even start, since the db was corrupted, it did indeed work accessing it directly and dropping/re-creating the table. However, I am still concerned about the fact that the database can even enter into this corrupted state. Currently, I have no idea what might be causing this - and apparently it is always the same table that gets impacted.

Comment: @joachim Are you still having this issue ?

Comment: @Ramesh at the moment, it's working fine without any problems.

Comment: Today the issue appeared again, the table civicrm_acl_contact_cache got corrupted. On file system level, the '.frm' file was there, but the '.ibd' file was missing. There is hardly any activity on this db, also disk space is not a problem.